# Mixins don't work after upgrading to vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to upgrade to Vue 3, and it looks like mixins don't work anymore.

My component:

```xml
<template>
  <div>{{testMethod()}}</div>
</template>

<script>
import testMixin from 'mixins/Test'

export default {
  mixins: [testMixin],
};
</script>
```

My mixin:

```js
console.log('TEST') // I do see this log in my browser, so I'm guessing the mixin is loaded correctly
const testMixin = {
  methods: {
    testMethod() {
      return 'HELLO'
    },
  },
};

export {
  testMixin,
};
```

Seems fine to me, but I get `TestComponent.vue:2 Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.testMethod is not a function`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in the `export` syntax, try to export the mixins as default:

```js
export default  testMixin;
```

or

```js
import {testMixin} from 'mixins/Test'
```

Comment: I have the same exception with  `export default  testMixin;`. Neither named nor unnamed mixins work. (And they worked in Vue 2).

Comment: try to create your component using `defineComponent` like `export default defineComponent({mixins: [testMixin]})`

Comment: I still get the same error. If this is really supposed to work with Vue 3, I guess I messed up with webpacker settings... Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I've tried it and it works perfectly using `import {testMixin} from 'mixins/Test`

Comment: I didn't downvote you! Okay, so my problem is not directly with vue, thanks again for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome, the problem should be related to Vue

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer:

Vue 3 added the composition API. While they didn't outright deprecate options API (old syntax), looks like you have to enable it or it won't work.

I added this to `webpack/environment.js` and everything is working:

```js
environment.plugins.prepend(
    'Define',
    new DefinePlugin({
        __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: true,
        __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: false
    })
)
```

Comment: My mixins works fine and i did not do that

Comment: @Lk77 Then I have no idea why I add to do that... Guess I'll still leave the answer, could help someone.

Comment: perhaps it's something new, i'm on 3.2.31